# How can I get Armenian language support in iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, internationalization

I find it strange that while the Armenian language (keyboard layouts and characters) is supported on OS X, on iOS it is not supported at all.

A jailbreak on iOS 3 allowed me to install iKeyEx from Cydia, which had an Armenian keyboard in it. This solution no longer works because the app is not supported. Besides, jailbreak probably isn't the answer.
There are 3rd party apps (like iTetr) that can be used for typing in Armenian.

How can I get Armenian language support in iOS?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We can't answer for why Apple made a particular decision; we just don't know. I've re-framed your question so that it asks for a solution to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. What does "re-framing" of the question do (or what does that mean?)

Comment: When I say 're-framing', I just mean that I've edited it to be a general question about how to add Armenian language support to iOS, instead of asking why it isn't there in the first place.

Comment: OK, now I see your edit. There is apparently a delay between your edit and when I can see it changed. Thanks for editing, it makes my question much more clear now.

Comment: I wanted to show you all what the Armenian keyboards look like. These are from Keyboard Viewer in Mac OS X: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yU196.png), [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/flXpX.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does have an Armenian font and can therefore display Unicode Armenian in emails, webpages, and text.  For input there are at least two apps that let you construct custom keyboards, and one of them, UniKey, comes with Armenian already:

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/05/custom-keyboards-for-ios-devices.html

Beyond that or jailbreaking, I think all you can do is ask Apple to add it via their feedback channel.

PS To see Armenian display on your iOS device you can go to

http://www.gov.am/am